# The value stored in a variable of static method has to be use in the another static method

Tags: apex

```
@AuraEnabled


public static SysConct_Provider_detail__c  getRecord()
{
    //string detail1 ;
    SysConct_Provider_detail__c detail=new SysConct_Provider_detail__c();
    detail.Name='';
    detail.SysConct_End_point_Url__c='';
    detail.Merchant_Id_encrypted__c='';
    detail.SysConct_Provider_Type__c='';
    detail.SysConct_Provider_Name__c='';
    detail.SysConct_Transaction_Type__c='';
    detail.SysConct_Transaction_Key__c='';
    detail.SysConct_Transaction_Object__c='';
    detail.SysConct_Tansaction_Related_List__c='';
    detail.SysConct_Source_object__c='--None--';
    detail.SysConct_Target_object__c='--None--';
    detail.SysConct_Source_Child_Object__c='--None--';
    detail.SysConct_Target_Child_Object__c='--None--';
    insert detail;
    return detail;

}

@AuraEnabled
public static void DeletingRecord(){
    // string storeid ;
    // system.debug('IDs'+storeid);
    //string[] idList  = new string[] {storeid};
   // system.debug('abc'+detail1);
    list<SysConct_Provider_detail__c> SPDList= new list<SysConct_Provider_detail__c> ();
    SPDList = [select id,name from SysConct_Provider_detail__c where id = : getRecord().Id ];
    system.debug('SPDList'+SPDList);
    delete SPDList ;
    system.debug('SPDList2'+SPDList);
    }
```

I have to pass the value stored in the getrecord method varibale  detail1 to DeletingRecord method detail1 variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ignore using a public static variable and just do something like this:

`MyClass.deletingRecord(MyClass.getRecord().Id);`

In the `getRecord()` method, simply use `insert detail;` and it'll automatically populate the Id in the detail variable itself.  So you can access the newly created Id with `detail.Id`

Comment: I tried it but the id generated in getrecord method is different from the deletingRecord getRecord().Id

Comment: Can you show the code you were trying to use to do this?  Not sure why the Ids would be different

Comment: Updated the code int he above code block.

Comment: can you please help

Comment: Hi - I don't understand the whole point of the `getRecord()` method.  It looks like it's just creating an empty record, and then the `deletingRecord()` method is deleting this empty record.  Why are you creating this empty record in the first place?

Comment: HI @BrainMiller , I'll use the getRecord() method in doInit function then it will create a record with id . In deletingRecord method i'll delete the record based on its ID,which i have fetched from getRecord method.

Comment: If `doInit` is creating a record, then calling `getRecord()` later isn't going to grab the original record created in `doInit` - it's going to create a separate record altogether, so you'll actually have two records from the `getRecord()` calls and just one `deleteRecord()` call.  I would suggest reviewing your code design and what you're trying to accomplish